# position slider active image in a static background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to position a slider active image inside a background image. i'm attaching a sample graphic layout. i need and idea and possible js library to do this.

[image]

slider should move behind the iphone image. only active image should display inside iphone background. can anyone help with a suggestion ?? thanks

CSS

```
.bxslider-slide {
  min-height: 350px;
}
.active-slide {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(http://pngimg.com/upload/iphone_PNG5729.png) 30 stretch; 
  -o-border-image: url(http://pngimg.com/upload/iphone_PNG5729.png) 30 stretch; 
  border-image: url(http://pngimg.com/upload/iphone_PNG5729.png) 30 stretch;
}
```

JS

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   slideWidth: 200,
   minSlides: 1,
   maxSlides: 5,
   moveSlides: 1,
   slideMargin: 10,

   onSliderLoad: function () {
     $('.bxslider>li:not(.bx-clone)').eq(3).addClass('active-slide');
   },
   onSlideAfter: function ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
    $('.bxslider-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    $($slideElement).next().next().next().addClass('active-slide');
   }
 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li class="bxslider-slide"><img src="http://clipart-library.com/data_images/459894.png" /></li>
    <li class="bxslider-slide"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT6/enK/dT6enKMnc.svg" /></li>
    <li class="bxslider-slide"><img src="http://clipart-library.com/data_images/459894.png" /></li>
    <li class="bxslider-slide"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT6/enK/dT6enKMnc.svg" /></li>
    <li class="bxslider-slide"><img src="http://clipart-library.com/data_images/459894.png" /></li>
    <li class="bxslider-slide"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT6/enK/dT6enKMnc.svg" /></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using bxslider from http://bxslider.com. on slide move event i added the iphone image as a border to the active image. it worked but when active class change from left image to right image iphone border also moves. can't prevent that. i'm trying to get iphone image stay static in position and only middle slider image to move.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yq6mbq40/6/
here is what i've done so far. its not working in fiddle. hope its not very difficult to understand by reading.

Comment: @Dhananjaya it is mandatory to set/unset the classes on the slides? is there any requirement as such or the requirement can be met in any way?

Comment: actually bxslider what i'm using here doesn't came up with with a active class. i added it my self. then i add css to active class to display iphone as border. how could it done without adding a class to that particular image i want the iphone over. and also this needs to be mobile responsive.

Comment: i would try another slider. i prefere owl-carousel2. its full-responsive. works with wrapper divs ( where you can include your iphone case i guess) and has a lot of settings.